# Set rights on parent Publication and permissions on Category and Keyword org item

Tags: 2013, authorization

1. How to set rights on parent Publication?
   I am able to set rights on all child Publications using Core Service API.
   Issue is with parent Publication. In our current CMS, parent Publication has rights setup. I am trying to modify these rights and find out how these rights were setup on parent Publication, or at some point was this a child Publication with rights changed to a parent Publication.

   > Error : Unable to save the Publication - No Parents have been added.
2. How to set permissions on Category and Keyword org item using Core Service call or even manually? 
   Can we only set permissions on individual Categories, not on the organization item? Tried with Core Service call:

   ```
   CategoryData organizationalItem = (CategoryData)client.Read("/webdav/010%20Schemas/Categories%20and%20Keywords", new ReadOptions());
   ```

   > Error: No items found for WebDAV URL(s): /webdav/010%20Schemas/Categories%20and%20Keywords.
3. If permissions are set on each Category, when a new Category is created, where does it inherit the permissions from?

Comment: Well, you are not loading Category, you are trying to load "Categories and Keyword", which is container for all categories. Please try to load Category itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second error is an expected one, you are trying to read the Categories and Keywords node, which isn't an Organizational item, it is just a node in the navigation tree. You can see that in the CME, as there are no properties for that node. So you are also unable to set rights and permissions on that, you have to set these on each Category separately.

For the first error, I'm wondering exactly what you are setting? The first error seems to indicate you are setting rights that are inherited from a parent, which isn't there for that Publication. I would suggest that you edit your question and supply a bit more detail to that part of the question.

## update

A top level parent Publication can never be changed to anything lower, also a Publication can never be added into a BluePrint unless it was already part of that BluePrint before. So with that knowledge, the error you mention still doesn't make sense, unless there is something wrong in your database. But without tangible details there isn't much more I can add to this answer.

As for your third question, When you create a new Category, it will be given read permissions to all Groups that have rights set in the Publication it is created in. It basically is up to the creator of the Category to set the correct permissions at creation time. Keywords will again inherit these settings once created.

Comment: Bart you got me by 30 seconds :D

Comment: @MarkoMilic I've had the complaint about me being too fast before :D

Comment: hahahahahhahahahahahahhah

Comment: @BartKoopman : Modified the question.